# Workaround for limited array in VBA + Selenium (HELP)

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

So I am working in this personal project in which I'm gathering data from football matches of a specific club for analysis. I have been working with VBA to populate my database, but I'm stuck with this error when trying to use FindElementsByTag that says my index is out of my array range. I'm definitely not an expert in VBA/Javascript since I'm learning how to use, but I really need help with this issue.

The line in which the error occurs is the following:

```
chutesCasa = CDbl(navegadorChrome.FindElementsByTag("td")(63).Attribute("innerText"))
```

Full code here:

```
Sub searchGoogle()

    priLin = Sheets("base").Range("V1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    jogoData = Sheets("base").Cells(priLin, 1).Value
    timeCasa = Sheets("base").Cells(priLin, 3).Value
    timeVisitante = Sheets("base").Cells(priLin, 4).Value

    Dim navegadorChrome As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    Query = jogoData & " " & timeCasa & " " & timeVisitante
    search_string = Replace(Query, " ", "+")
    
    linkGoogle = "http://google.com/search?q=" & search_string
    
    navegadorChrome.Get (linkGoogle)
    
    navegadorChrome.FindElementByClass("YIikAd").Click
    
chutesCasa = CDbl(navegadorChrome.FindElementsByTag("td")(63).Attribute("innerText"))
    Sheets("base").Cells(priLin, 22).Value = chutesCasa
    
    chutesVisitante = CDbl(navegadorChrome.FindElementsByTag("td")(64).Attribute("innerText"))
    Sheets("base").Cells(priLin, 23).Value = chutesVisitante

    navegadorChrome.Quit

End Sub
```

I tried to somehow increase the array range, but I don't really know how to do it and it didn't work.

Comment: Isn't it `FindElementsByTagName` ? https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_FindElementsByTagName.htm

Comment: Apparently no :(. Tried it now and it only displayed another error (This object does not accept this property or method) - sorry if the translation isn't correct, my software is in another language.

Comment: In that case, the `63` in this part `FindElementsByTag("td")(63)` is too large. How many TD elements are there? Did you check? `FindElementsByTag("td").Count`

Comment: perhaps try a different strategy such as xpath with text match or css positional relationship match. What's the URI and which line produces the error? Setting matches into a variable and checking  .count can be a useful technique before conditional indexing. Avoid hardcoded indexing where possible unless high confidence position won't change.

Comment: There are exactly 94 td elements in the html page (https://www.google.com/search?q=09/04/2022+Fluminense+Santos#sie=m;/g/11sp98nyvz;2;/m/0fnk7q;dt;fp;1;;;). I've tried to use XPath but had a hard time trying to write it.

Comment: Just discovered it: I had to put a line of code to wait for the page to load:

    navegadorChrome.Wait (5000)